# Where/how can I fight stuff in the starter Mustang Alpha ship?

Tags: star-citizen

I purchased a starter package consisting of a Mustang Alpha ship. Whenever I travel to a Comm Array to do an open-world mission, it inevitably gets destroyed after only a few volleys. I've looked into buying some modules, but I can't really afford any at this time. This leads to a few related questions with the goal of having fun in the ship I purchased.

- Is there any combat-oriented places I can take my ship and at least have it survive long enough to possibly destroy other ships?
- How can I earn additional UEC so I can purchase upgrades?
- What are some optimal upgrades I should look to get to make my ship more viable in combat engagements?

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that, as of today (23/01/16), Star Citizen is still very firmly in the actual definition of Alpha - i.e. not feature complete. All of the stuff I mention below will change in the next few years.

> Can I fight stuff in a Mustang Alpha?

If I'm honest, I would suggest getting a handle on the combat before trying to fight in Crusader (if you're having trouble with the pirates). I recommend this because of the decreased time between respawning and being able to practice.
Places you can do this include:

- The flight tutorial (which is unfortunately bugged in the current build, 2.1(.1)
- Vanduul Swarm (Arena Commander)

Of the two, due to the bugs, AC / Vanduul Swarm is the best option, as you can also play with other players (as well as being able to earn REC).

> How can I earn additional UEC to purchase upgrades?

Currently you cannot earn UEC in game. You can purchase it for roughly 1000/1$, but don't do that - in fact, don't spend UEC at the moment, as everything is still very far from final.

However, you can earn REC (Rental Equipment Credit) by playing public games of Arena Commander - including Vanduul Swarm. When you have earnt sufficient REC, you can rent equipment to use with your ship in the [Electronic Access store](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/electronic-access) (as well as other ships).

> What are some upgrades I can get for the Mustang Alpha to make it better in combat?

Based on the ship data available [here](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/pledge/ships/mustang/Mustang-Alpha), we can see that the Mustang Alpha comes with two gimballed M3A Laser Cannons (on the nose), and two unused S1 hardpoints (under the wings). It also has an S2 shield slot, but only comes with an INK-1 (S1).

Assuming your powerplant can handle it, you could upgrade the shield to an S2 (such as the `INK-MARK 204-ID` or `INK-MARK 204-IS`, which protect better against projectiles and missiles respectively), and add two S1 weapons to the unused mounts (even replacing the M3As, if you prefer other weapons).

Comment: I haven't added how to get to AC / Vanduul Swarm, as I think it's out of scope for the question / we can assume you know how to do that. However, if you'd like it added, let me know.

Comment: No, I know how. I've done the training missions multiple times. This answer seems to imply it is a question of skill. While I wouldn't consider myself highly skilled, I should point out that as soon as my ship registers that the shields ate taking hits, my ship is destroyed. So, unless you can become skilled enough so that you can destroy the pirates without getting hit ever, I don't think you can kill them in a Mustang. Maybe if there's only one pirate ship.